# linear algebra, simple sum - considerations

Tags: linear-algebra

$X$ is linear space, and $U,V$ are subspaces of $X$ such that $X=U\oplus V$.
Is it true that $\forall x\in X (x\in U \Rightarrow x\notin V)$ ?
For me, it is true;
Each vector $x\in X$ can be unambiguously expressed as the sum of two vectors $x=u+v$ such that $u\in U$, $v\in V$.  If $x\in U\wedge x\in V$ then $x=x+0_V = x+0_U $.  Contradiction.

Am I right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $U$ and $V$ are subspaces of $X$, so they both contain $0$. But it's true that $U$ and $V$ have no non-zero vectors in common. Depending on how you define internal direct sums, this may be part of the definition.

Comment: So, what is true answer to this question ?

Comment: $U\cap V=\{0\}$. So the statement that $x\in U$ implies $x\not\in V$ fails for the zero vector, but is otherwise true.

Answer (score 0):

$X=U\oplus V \Leftrightarrow U\cap V=0_{X} \ \ $ and $ \ \ U+V=X$